# Beginner Programmer trying to get flask buttons working from a form

Tags: python, html, flask

I am a beginner programmer looking for some help with my code. This is my first attempt at this. I have only been programming for a little while now and have hit a rode block.
Here is the flask for a button that I am trying to make work:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort, url_for
import os

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
        @app.route('/home', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
        def run_home():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.form['bob'] == 'home':
                pass
            return redirect('home', code=302, Response=None)
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

Here is the html that is associated with the flask above. I need help making the buttons work and have gotten stuck. I am trying to use a table to arrange the buttons that link to the different pages. Can anyone help me with figuring out how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="List of Comics">
        <meta name="author" content="Zach">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <h1 align="center">List of Comics</h1>
        <br />
    </head>
    <header>
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td><form method ="post" name="bob" action="url_for('home')}}" class="buttons to new page" id="home"><input type="submit" value="Home" name="Home"></form></td>
                <td><form method ="post" name="bob" action="url_for('books')}}" class="buttons to new page" id="books"><input type="submit" value="Books" name="Books"></form></td>
                <td><form method ="post" name="bob" action="url_for('comics')}}" class="buttons to new page" id="issues"><input type="submit" value="Issues" name="Issues"></form></td>
                <td><form method ="post" name="bob" action="url_for('bio')}}" class="buttons to new page" id="bio"><input type="submit" value="Biography" name="Biography"></form></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </header>
    <body>
        <a href="books.html"><h2 align="center">Books</h2></a>
        <br />
        <p align="center">These are books containing collections of issues.</p>
        <a href="comics.html"><h2 align="center">Issues</h2></a>
        <br />
        <p align="center" a href="comics.html">These are individual issues.</p>

    </body>
    <footer>
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <tr><form method ="post" name="bob" action="/home" class="buttons to new page">
                <td><input type="submit" value="Home" name="Home" formaction="/home.html" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Books" name="Books" formaction="/comics.html" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Issues" name="Issues" formaction="/issues.html" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Biography" name="Biography" formaction="/bio.html" /></td>
            </form></tr>
        </table>
        <p align="right">Date/Time: <span id="datetime"></span></p>
        <script>
        var dt = new Date();
        document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString();
        </script>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Which buttons aren't working? are they being unresponsive or are they resulting in an error? check your terminal and include the traceback if you can

Comment: I am trying to make this buttons link to another page.

Comment: As a sidenote, your html is invalid, as `<header>` and `<footer>` should be inside `<body>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `form`, you could instead create `<button></button>` elements. If you want each button to go somewhere, you can enclose them in an `<a>` tag, specifying the location in the `href` attribute.

The reason yours is not working is that you're using submit buttons to a form. A form should A) only have one submit button (usually) and B) include form data (such as username, password, email, etc.).

Using the `name` attribute on a form element won't work. It's looking for a value, but a `form` element doesn't have one; an *input* does.

So in short:

```
<a href="/home"><button value="Home"></button></a>
<a href="/books"><button value="Books"></button></a>
<a href="/issues"><button value="Issues"></button></a>
<a href="/biography"><button value="Biography"></button></a>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it to work with some tweaking the flask and html code a little with your a tag help.

Comment: Anytime! Best of luck to your Flask endeavors. :-)